# What is the best approach for this project?

Tags: android, ios, database, push-notification

I'm planning to build an app for iOS and Android where the user has an account and can add friends. He can also post something, just like on facebook and all of his friends get a push notification and can react to it.
My question is: Which technologies do I need to use to accomplish this? A webservice with a database in the background? Can I do this with XAMPP?
Before going native, I wanna try out Appcelerator Titanium, any tips you can give me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is "webservice with a database in the background" & your middleware should send the notification to platform server which will notify to individual devices for push notification.